# how to call aws api gateway authorized

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, amazon-cognito, api-gateway

How can I invoke an API call of AWS API Gateway from python? The api is secured with an authorizer setup with cognito.

I can authenticate with a cognito-idp like shown this:

```
response = client.initiate_auth(
    ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
    AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username, "PASSWORD": password},
)
```

and I get a AccessToken from that. But how do I use that for a request? My API is something like

```
https://api_id.execute-api.mydomain.tld/dev/get_database_entry/
```

and I try calling it with requests:

```
response = requests.get(API_URL, auth=[??])
```

Comment: you'll add it as a header, something like `{'Authorization': f'Bearer {your_token}'}`

Comment: that doesn't work for me. I get "Authorization header requires \'Credential\' parameter." ... and some other required header information.